# How to direct the same Amazon S3 events into several different SQS queues?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I'm working with AWS Lambda functions (in Python), that process new files that appear in the same Amazon S3 bucket and folders.

When new file appears in `s3:/folder1/folderA, B, C`, an event `s3:ObjectCreated:*` is generated and it goes into `sqs1`, then processed by `Lambda1` (and then deleted from `sqs1` after successful processing).

I need the same event related to the same new file that appears in `s3:/folder1/folderA` (but not folderB, or C) to go also into `sqs2`, to be processed by `Lambda2`. `Lambda1` modifies that file and saves it somewhere, `Lambda2` gets that file into DB, for example.

But AWS docs says that:

> Notification configurations that use Filter cannot define filtering rules with overlapping prefixes, overlapping suffixes, or prefix and suffix overlapping.

So question is how to bypass this limitation? Are there any known recommended or standard solutions?

Comment: Your description is a bit confusing. Are you saying that you want files appearing in `folderA` to send a message to both `sqs1` and `sqs2`, but files appearing in `folderB` and `folderC` should only send messages to `sqs1`?

Comment: Messages from new files in folderA, folderB, folderC should go to sqs1, and sqs2 should have only messages from folderA (so there is overlap)

Comment: Yes, so is it correct that messages from `folderA` should go to both `sqs1` and `sqs2`, but messages from `folderB` and `folderC` should go only to `sqs1`?

Comment: Yes, it's correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that your requirement is:

- When a file is added to `folderA`, you wish to send a message to `sqs1` *AND* `sqs2` (can be done in parallel)
- When a file is added to `folderB`, you wish to send a message to `sqs2`

This can be done by configuring **separate events for each folder**:

- Event A: `Prefix = folderA`
- Event B: `Prefix = folderB`
- Event C: `Prefix = folderC`

You can then use an Amazon SNS topic to **fan-out** to multiple queues:

```
eventA -> sns1 +-> sqs1 -> Lambda1
               |
               +-> sqs2 -> Lambda2

eventB -> sqs1 -> Lambda1

eventC -> sqs1 -> Lambda1
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of set up the S3 object notification of (S3 -> SQS), you should set up a notification of (S3 -> Lambda).

In your lambda function, you parse the S3 event and then you write your own logic to send whatever content about the S3 event to whatever SQS queues you like.

Comment: It was my original idea. Unfortunately it doesn't work due to pipeline requirements: s3 bucket attached to lambda should be created (and destroyed, if something goes wrong) by the pipeline, at the moment of deployment. It doesn't work in my case, i have to deal with existing s3 with a lot of data saved there. SQS is known workaround for this problem.

Comment: It probably would work with additional 'special' LambdaSpecial that reads messages from one sqsSpecial attached to s3 events and splits messages to 2 (or more) corresponding SQS, attached to Lambda1 and Lambda2. Looks complicated though, I hope there is simpler / better way to do it.

Comment: well, didn't know you have such requirements. And you are making me confused. Well John's answer is simpler to implement your sqs logic -- as long as you don't give us other requirements for surprise. ;)

Comment: Yes, sorry, in reality there are ~hundred folders, and dozens of 'folderA' which have to have shared events among few SQS. I just tried to describe it as simple as possible, to get an idea how to deal with this situation

Answer (score 0):

To send the same S3 events, Event FolderA to SQS1 and SQS2 - Send the event to SNS Topic and subscribe your SQS queues to the topic [SQS1 and SQS2]